# from django.db import models in models.py but in command prompt i got NameError: name 'model' is not defined

Tags: django, import, model, pipenv

i got an this error:
File "C:\Users\jiri.svab\Documents\Pipenv\Django\DennisIvy\ecommerce\store\models.py", line 15, in 
class Product(models.Model):
File "C:\Users\jiri.svab\Documents\Pipenv\Django\DennisIvy\ecommerce\store\models.py", line 16, in Product
name = model.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
**NameError: name 'model' is not defined**

But in my "**models.py**" in the first line i have imported the model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Any clue what i should look for please?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown the rest of the models.py file but it seems to be a typo in your `Product` model class definition. In the line `name = model.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)` change from `model` to `models`.

Comment: Oh yea, you are right, i actually posted and answer for myself yesterday but somehow it didnt get saved here. Just writing about the problem once again helped me to realize a typo mistake. Anyway thank you.